# POI Line chart axis position and other issues

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

I'm dealing with POI to create charts and I've some issues. 
First, even if I change the AxisPosition I always have x-axis at bottom and y-axis at left. Second I would like to have 2 y-axis. Here's a part of my code:

Function to create the chart:

```
private XSSFChart createChart(Sheet sheet,int[] anchors, String xLabel, String yLabel, String title){

    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(anchors[0], anchors[1], anchors[2],
 anchors[3], anchors[4], anchors[5], anchors[6], anchors[7] );
    XSSFChart chart = (XSSFChart) drawing.createChart(anchor);
    ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);
    ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.TOP);
    ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    ValueAxis rightAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
//Function to set axis title took from how-to-set-axis-labels-in-a-line-chart-using-apache-poi
    setValueAxisTitle(chart,0,yLabel);
    setValueAxisTitle(chart,0,"Second Axis");
    setCatAxisTitle(chart,0,xLabel);
    chart.setTitle(title);
    chart.getAxis();

    return chart;

}
```

Code to plot chart

```
XSSFChart chart1=createChart(sheet,anchor1,"Temps","Courbes",title );
LineChartData dataM3s = chart1.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();
ChartDataSource<Number> yM3s = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, 
    new CellRangeAddress(3, (numOfRows / numOfColumns) + 2, colToWrite, colToWrite));
LineChartSeries chartSeriesM3s =  dataM3s.addSeries(xs, yM3s);
chartSeriesM3s.setTitle(metric.getLibelle());
chart1.plot(dataOther, chart1.getAxis().get(0), chart1.getAxis().get(1));
//By the way, this works as well:
//chart1.plot(dataM3s, new ChartAxis[] { chart1.getAxis().get(0), chart1.getAxis().get(1)});
```

When I change

```
chart1.plot(dataOther, chart1.getAxis().get(0), chart1.getAxis().get(1));
```

by

```
chart1.plot(dataOther, chart1.getAxis().get(0), chart1.getAxis().get(2));
```

I can't open my xlsx file (and as soon as try to create a second value axis): i got message like "unreadable content". sometimes excel suceed in reparing and tells me it repared the drawing shape in /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml. I got this error: error062800_01.xml but not familiar with XML.

If anyone has some idea